# Highlight/mark/indicate certain lines in LaTeX in Emacs

Tags: emacs, latex, syntax-highlighting

I use Emacs to edit LaTeX source. I preface notes which I have made with `%` as required, so that they are considered as comments. These lines appear in Emacs in a different face.

However, when working on a document, I sometimes would like to highlight/indicate/mark certain lines so that they appear in a different face. For example, if I am done with a section of notes I have made, but would like to keep these in the source file, I would like to "flag" these lines so that they appear in a different face in Emacs.

Is there a way to do this? Any solution would obviously still need to be considered valid LaTeX code. Maybe lines starting with `%%` could use a different face?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a great idea, thanks for making me go and find a solution! What you need to do is add the following lines to your `~/.emacs` file:

```
(add-hook 'tex-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (font-lock-add-keywords nil
       '(("\\(%%.*\\)" 1
        font-lock-warning-face t)))))
```

You can change the `%%` to anything else you want. Personally, I think I will use `%#` that way I can still have stretches of `%` for horizontal separators.

Comment: Thanks :) I changed it to `'LaTeX-mode-hook` to get it to work on my system. I think I'll go with `%#` too, for the same reason.

Comment: Just for clarity: I'm using `AUCTex` and `LaTeX-mode` is what it calls it's LaTeX mode. I think the default LaTeX mode in Emacs may be called `latex-mode`.